# How do I create a line style including SVG symbols?

Tags: geotools

Is it possible in GeoTools to draw SVG symbols repeatedly along a line?

```
    Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(lineColor), ff.literal(width));
    LineSymbolizer lineSym = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, null);
```

---

Tried this after the 2 first comments, but there is still something missing with the icon setup. The original line is drawn ok, but the icon-stroke draws my "backup"-mark (circle) instead of the SVG-icon. I suspect I should use:

```
Graphic symbol = sf.graphic(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(size), null, null, null);
PointSymbolizer pointSym =  sf.createPointSymbolizer(symbol, null);
```

But I can't implement it in my test code:

```
Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(outlineColor), ff.literal(lineWidth), ff.literal(lineOpacity), null, null, dashArray, null, null, null);
Stroke strokeIcon = sf.createStroke(null, null);
ExternalGraphic graphic = sf.createExternalGraphic(
    "file:///C:\\Temp\\cog4.svn" +
    "?fill=#AA3333" + 
    "&fill-opacity=0.5" + 
    "&outline=#AA0000" + 
    "&outline-opacity=1.0" +
    "&outline-width=1"
    , "image/svg+xml");
List<GraphicalSymbol> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
symbols.add(graphic);
Mark mark = sf.createMark(ff.literal("circle"), stroke, fill, ff.literal(7), ff.literal(0));
symbols.add(mark);
//Graphic symbol = sf.graphic(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(35), null, null, null);
//PointSymbolizer pointSym =  sf.createPointSymbolizer(symbol, null);
GraphicStroke gs=null;
try {
    //                               transp           size            ?????
    gs = sf.graphicStroke(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(7), ff.literal(25), sf.anchorPoint(ff.literal(0.5),ff.literal(0.5)), sf.displacement(ff.literal(0),ff.literal(0)), ff.literal(25), ff.literal(25));
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
strokeIcon.setGraphicStroke(gs);
LineSymbolizer lineIcon = sf.createLineSymbolizer(strokeIcon, null);
LineSymbolizer lineSym = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, null);
return wrapSymbolizers(lineIcon, lineSym);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a [`GraphicStroke`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/opengis/style/GraphicStroke.html) which is created using [`StyleFactory.graphicStroke()`](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/styling/StyleFactory.html#graphicStroke-java.util.List-org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression-org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression-org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression-org.opengis.style.AnchorPoint-org.opengis.style.Displacement-org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression-org.opengis.filter.expression.Expression-) which takes a list of `GraphicalSymbols` that the renderer will work through in order until it finds one it can draw.

To create a GraphicStroke you need something like:

```
gs = sf.graphicStroke(symbols, ff.literal(1.0), ff.literal(6), ff.literal(0), sf.anchorPoint(0.5,0.5), sf.displacement(ff.literal(0),ff.literal(0)), ff.literal(0), ff.literal(0));
```

Comment: I updated my original question, I can't quite get it to work.

Comment: I can't get it to draw the SVN-icon, it only draws my "backup"-mark (circle).

Comment: does debug level logging show anything? Most likely issue is not being able to find or read the svg

Comment: No it didn't show anything, but when you pointed this out I can see that I hard coded the file name wrong ".svn" instead of ".svg". Now it works, sorry. Can you please tell me how to configure the distance between the symbols along the line?

Comment: Change the gap parameter from 0 to some small value

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
PointSymbolizer pointSym = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, null);

LineSymbolizer lineSym = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, pointSym);
```

Comment: sf.createLineSymbolizer(..) takes the arguments (Stroke, String), not (Stroke, PointSymbolizer)